# Есть ли в русском языке суффикс Ж?

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Также вопрос касается форманта ***ЖД***.

В словаре у Ефремовой суффикс ***Ж*** не указан.

У Тихонова в словах на ***СТЬ*** происходит чередование ***С/Ж***, суффикс нулевой: ***пропасть — пропаж/а, красть — краж/а***. В Интернете можно встретить разборы, где выделяется суффикс Ж.

Но (у Тихонова): ***продать — прода/ж/а***, суффикс ***Ж***.

Слова ***одежда*** и ***надежда*** у Тихонова разобраны по-разному: *оде/ть — одежд/а, наде/я/ть/ся — надеж/д/а.*

Форманты ЖД или Ж добавлены к корню.

**Всё ли это верно и как это можно объяснить?**

Интересно, как в школе  разбираются эти слова.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

В словаре Ефремовой отыскался ряд суффиксов на Ж, это **АЖ, ЁЖ и ЁЖК**: *массаж, инструктаж, шпионаж, крепёж, галдёж; грабёж, чертёж;  кормёжка, бомбёжка, зубрёжка, сладкоежка*.

Может быть, **суффикс Ж** — это всё-таки вариант **суффикса АЖ** при образовании существительного от глагола: *пропасть — пропа/ж/а, продать — прода/ж/а*?

Comment: На сайте http://www.textologia.ru/  в слове продажа ж - корень.  Там говорится, что "словарь  coздaн нa мaтepиaлax aвтopитeтныx yчeбныx пocoбий и cлoвapeй, cpeди кoтopыx мoжнo выдeлить: «Cлoвapь мopфeм pyccкoгo языкa» A.И. Kyзнeцoвoй и T.Ф. Eфpeмoвoй; «Cлoвapь yникaльныx мopфeм coвpeмeннoгo pyccкoгo языкa» Л.B. Paцибypcкoй; «Mopфeмнo-opфoгpaфичecкий cлoвapь» P.И. Aвaнecoвa и C.И. Oжeгoвa".

Comment: Т. е. разные лингвисты придерживаются разного мнения. Но найти суффикса ж мне не удалось найти.  Мне представляется более правильным чередование в корне.

Comment: Но спрошу на аск.фм. Может, им попадался такой суффикс.

Comment: Да, Серж, спросите. Мне кажется, что суффикс всё-таки есть. А не знаете, как там у Морковкина разбираются эти слова. Его словаря, кажется, нет онлайн.

Comment: К сожалению, у меня нет этого словаря. А в Интернете,его, действительно, нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что ответили специалисты экстренной лингвистической помощи (сайт ask.fm).

Ответ 1. Да, такой суффикс есть, он участвует в образовании ряда отглагольных существительных. Чередование, о котором идет речь в вопросе, имеет исторический характер.

Ответ 2. Это связано с регулярными фонетическими чередованиями на ранних стадиях развития русского языка: краСТь / краДет / краЖа, но: продаТь / прода-J-от / прода-Ж-а. Чередования первого типа в языке были регулярными, а вот чередований второго типа не было - следовательно, в первом случае мы имеем дело с т. н. морфонологическими процессами, во втором - с морфемными. Что касается выделения -ж- как самостоятельного корня, эта точка зрения представляется нам очень дискуссионной.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, "ж" в слове "продажа", всё же относится  к корню, так как для мн.ч. глагола существуют такие формы как "прода**д**ут, прода**д**им и прода**д**ите", а для 3 лица ед.ч имеется форма прода**с**т. Помимо этого, ранее (в старослав.) для 3 лица ед.ч. аориста существовала также форма прода**д**е (продал). Кроме того, если говорить об этимологии, то русский глагол "дать" и итал. "dare" вроде являются родственниками, а у последнего в одном из прошедших времён ([Indicativo passato remoto](https://www.babla.ru/%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/dare)) также наблюдается "выползание" означенной буквы.